# Java 8 functional interface (Consumer) additional parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

Is it possible to somehow parametrize Java 8 Consumer? I want to have reusable Consumer where I can put additional arguments in place where I use it.

```
List<DateTime> dates = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
Set<Alarm> alarms = new HashSet<Alarm>();

Consumer<Entry> entryConsumer1 = entry -> {
    LocalTime time = entry.getDate().toLocalTime();
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm(time, calendar1.getPattern());
    alarms.add(alarm);
    dates.add(entry.getDate());
};

Consumer<Entry> entryConsumer2 = entry -> {
    LocalTime time = entry.getDate().toLocalTime();
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm(time, calendar2.getPattern());
    alarms.add(alarm);
    dates.add(entry.getDate());
};

calendar1.generateEntries(criteria).forEach(entryConsumer1);
calendar2.generateEntries(criteria).forEach(entryConsumer2);
```

calendar1, calendar2 are the same type

As you can see both consumers differ only in one argument. Is it possible to simplify this code/don't duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a factory method for your consumers:

```
public Consumer<Entry> createConsumer(Calendar calendar, Set<Alarm> alarms, List<DateTime> dates) {
    return entry -> {
        LocalTime time = entry.getDate().toLocalTime();
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm(time, calendar.getPattern());
        alarms.add(alarm);
        dates.add(entry.getDate());
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
calendar1.generateEntries(criteria).forEach(createConsumer(calendar1, alarms, dates));
calendar2.generateEntries(criteria).forEach(createConsumer(calendar2, alarms, dates));
```

But also: It is bad practice (against functional programming principles) to have a lambda expression or function with side effects, such as adding alarms to the set of alarms or adding dates to the list of dates inside the lambda. A more functional approach would be to use transformation methods like `map` and then collect the results. For example:

```
Set<Alarm> alarms = calendar1.generateEntries(criteria)
    .map(entry -> new Alarm(entry.getDate().toLocalTime(), calendar1.getPattern()))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: While using `collect` is better, Java doesn't have a good way of producing two results i.e. `alarms` and `dates` from one stream.

Comment: @Jesper While "functional programming principles" do discourage the reliance on side-effects, note that the functional interface `Consumer<T>` _exists exclusively for_ the purpose of modeling side-effect-ful computations.  It returns nothing -- so if it represented a pure function, the abstraction would be useless.  (It is the case that stream methods like `forEach()` are often used when `collect()` or `reduce()` could do the job better -- but assuming the choice to use `Consumer` was sound, it makes no sense to then criticize the side effects inherent in implementing `Consumer`.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz thanks for the comment, I understand, I wanted to mention this because I often see people with no functional programming experience use `forEach` with side-effecting lambdas for everything, instead of thinking "the functional way".

Answer (score 4):

What we do is change the API, though it is not a simple option here.

```
BiConsumer<String, Entry> entryConsumer = (pattern, entry) -> {
    LocalTime time = entry.getDate().toLocalTime();
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm(time, pattern);
    alarms.add(alarm);
    dates.add(entry.getDate());
};
```

and call the API like this (where the first argument is passed to each call to entryConsumer)

```
.forEach(calendar1.getPattern, entryConsumer);
```

However, say you can't change the API, what you can do is use a method like this.

```
calendar1.generateEntries(criteria).forEach(e -> entryConsumer(calendar1, e));
calendar2.generateEntries(criteria).forEach(e -> entryConsumer(calendar2, e));

public static void entryConsumer(Calendar cal, Entry e) {
    LocalTime time = entry.getDate().toLocalTime();
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm(time, cal.getPattern());
    alarms.add(alarm);
    dates.add(entry.getDate());
};
```

Comment: I would prefer the "external" method but you can also use `BiConsumer` without altering the  API since it has one: `.forEach(e -> entryConsumer.accept(calendar1, e))`